# Joining a container to a domain

Tags: containers

I am running Windows Server 2016 on a VM through Hyper-V manager on my pc. I have created a container using a Windows Server Core image, however I am required to join this container to a domain that I have created using the Server 2016 VM, which is the Domain controller. Is it possible to connect a container to this domain?